# How to override paragraph remove button template?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

How to override paragraph remove button template? or Is there any way to alter the functionality of remove button provided by paragraph module?

Comment: hook_form_alter maybe?

Comment: hook_form_alter() always works, but why exactly should it be hidden? The delete button respects access permissions, so if you take that away from users with a custon entity access hook or the provided paragraphs type access module, then the remove button should be hidden automatically.